# RegEx CRLF but preserve CRLF with preceding character

Tags: regex

I have a text file with the following content:

```
aaaaaaCRLF
bbbbbb'CRLF
ccccccCRLF
```

I want the remove the `CRLF` in the lines where there is no `'` before the `CRLF`. The destination text should be:

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb'CRLF
cccccc
```

Any idea on how to do this with RegEx?

Comment: Which language are you using? Have a look at this regex: [`(?<!')CRLF`](https://regex101.com/r/tQ6oN9/1)

Comment: `CRLF` implies  literal text from your example, i hope its not Windows EOL format

Comment: ritesht93: I should have been more specific. In fact, the CRLF is the Windows EOL and no printed characters.

Comment: @PeterTL this regex should work using negative lookbehind assertion: Find for `(?<!')\r\n` and replace by nothing

Comment: AKS: I receive the content in CSV format and I have to load it into a database via Talend. The source text contains CRLFs in between the fields and not only at the EOL.

I am planning to write a little Java or command script to execute the RegEx on the CSV file before loading it.

Comment: If the regex flavor is PCRE/Boost, I'd rather use `(?<!')\R`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Python, but this should work with any decent Regex engine. Use a negative lookbehind!

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "aaaaaaa\r\nasdasdasd'\r\nasdasdas\r\n"
>>> p = r"(?<!')\r\n"
>>> re.sub(p, '', s)
"aaaaaaaasdasdasd'\r\nasdasdas"
```

edit: Oh, you mean `\r\n`. Pattern adapted.

Comment: @AKS Just saw it, changed the pattern.